# "Anti-Leibniz order"

Tags: terminology, gm.general-mathematics

It seems that some people use the term "anti-Leibniz order" for what I'd call the "diagrammatic order" of composition: writing $f;g$ for the composition of $f$ and $g$ instead of $g\circ f$.

(I have no intention to discuss which order is "better"; I use both depending on context.  Also, I believe the confusion is due to the fact that we forgot to mirror decimal numbers when we copied the concept from Arabic.  For a reference to "anti-Leibniz", see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor.)

Now, where does that terminology come from, and what does Leibniz have to do with it?

Comment: Is it possible that the terminology comes from ncatlab? It's also used at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/composition where reference is made to "the notation introduced by the followers of Leibniz for composition of functions."

Comment: Oh, I'd overlooked that one, thank you. Now, do people use "anti-Leibniz" outside of ncatlab?

Comment: I am pretty close to the "inside" of ncatlab, and have never heard this name. I would call it "French".

Comment: Or, sometimes, "reverse Polish".